# Losing the logic! Random unique numbers in javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, numbers

I needed to write a function that'd generate 6 random numbers between 0 and 60 and then store them in a given array. In addition, this function could not store duplicates in the returned array. Well, I found a very helpful answer here on StackOverflow(Thanks Shouvik) which I'm showing below.

But here's the thing guys I had most of this logic but missed two core elements

1. I was trying to do this without a second temporary Array
2. I had no clue how'd I find duplicates inside the array

I knew I had to .indexOF the array
I knew I had to .push a new value to the array

Here is the code I had prior to finding the solution:

```
function gerarDezenas() {
  let jogo = [];
  for (var i = 0;i < 6;i++) {
    jogo.push(Math.round(Math.random()*(1 , 60)+1));

    if (jogo.indexOf(jogo) == //clueless)c{
         .push() // ?? clueless either
    }
  }

  return jogo
}
console.log(gerarDezenas())
```

So I found that I needed another Array and the if condition to compare it to

```
function gerarDezenas() {
  let jogo = []; 
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var temp = Math.round(Math.random()*(1 , 60)+1);
    if (jogo.indexOf(temp) == -1) {
        jogo.push(temp)
    }
    else {
        i--;
    }
  }
  return jogo
}
```

The code is now working as it was intended to but I don't really understand it and that the issue here! I don't know what these lines are doing:

```
if (jogo.indexOf(temp) == -1) {
    jogo.push(temp)
}
else {
      i--;
}
```

Can somebody clarify to me what the if and the else are doing?

If you read through the post thank you very much!

[attached image please don't hate me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJqHA.png)

Answer (score 0):

if temp (random number) is not in jogo array (indexOf always returns -1 if value isn't found)

```
if (jogo.indexOf(temp) == -1)
```

```js
const arr = ["A","B","C"];
console.log(arr.indexOf("D"));
console.log(arr.indexOf("C"));
```

then add it to the array

```
jogo.push(temp)
```

otherwise redo the loop in hopes of a number that isn't in jogo array (-- would counteract the ++ )

```
 i--;
```

```js
let i = 5;
i--
i++
console.log(i);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I still dont get what is making sure there're no duplicates inside the array!
is it the .indexOf or the -1 compressing? or is it both?

Comment: @SamuelPantoja the statement  jogo.indexOf(temp) returns a positive value or 0 if temp is present in jogo, if temp is not present it will return -1. so  ```jogo.indexOf(temp) == -1``` says if it's not present then insert so the whole if block code takes care of inserting unique values to the array.

Comment: @SamuelPantoja it's both; the loop can't advance when temp already exists in the array, so it keeps repeating until temp is not a duplicate. Ultimately, it's not an efficient solution because it can take anyway from 5 tries to 1,000,000+ (though the latter is unlikely) .

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Check whether array named jogo has the temp element inside it, if not add the temp element to jogo. */
if (jogo.indexOf(temp) == -1){
    jogo.push(temp)
    }

/*When you are inside this if else block the i's value must have been increased, now if
temp is not being inserted because it's already there in the array, decrement i so that the if else block again runs with the same I what it was earlier before increment.
*/
    else {
      i--;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code loops through the whole array to check if the random number is inside the array. But if not it will output -1 which says that the current random number has no repeats

```
if (jogo.indexOf(temp) == -1)
```

While this code just reverse the loop so it cancels the i++.

```
i--;
```